# Why can't I use RSA OAEP padding when encrypting with a private key?

Tags: ruby, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm generating a license key payload that is encrypted with RSA using the private key, which is then decrypted using the public key to utilize the license payload in my user-facing software. I'm encrypting instead of signing so I only need to deliver a single string to my user, rather than delivering a key and a signature.

But I'm having trouble using OAEP padding with private key encryption:

```
require 'openssl'

padding = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA::PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
priv = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new 2048
pub = priv.public_key

# FIXME: Why can't I use OAEP padding with private key encryption?
data = 'customer:foo@example.com;allowances:25;users:5;locked:true;'
enc = priv.private_encrypt data, padding
dec = pub.public_decrypt enc, padding

puts dec == data
```

Repl: https://repl.it/repls/LavishEarnestWifi.

Running this throws an error: `unknown padding type`. Encrypting with the public key allows me to use OAEP, but not the private key. Using PKCS1 padding works, however. I thought using PKCS1 was insecure and OAEP was recommended? I'd like to be able to encrypt the same payload and get different license keys, like I would be able to with OAEP padding.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a bad thing to do; signature generation is only proven to be secure when using a padding scheme that is targeting signature generation. And actually PKCS#1 v1.5 padding for signature generation and encryption is *different* even if they are often given the same name.

What you seem to be looking for is a signature scheme with (partial) message recovery. Those aren't used that often anymore. One reason for that is because ECDSA signatures are much smaller than RSA signatures (twice the ECC key size, which would be about 64 bytes for a very secure 256 bit curve).

---

There are a few signature generation methods giving message recovery specified [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/11748/1172) (ISO 9796). Those are a bit old and dangerous, especially if an attacker can somehow influence the input message. Generally they do suffice though. For  a really secure scheme there is [PSS giving message recovery, officially known as EMSR-PSS, specified [in section 1.3 of the paper: PSS: Provably secure encoding method for digital signatures by Bellare and Rogaway](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b459/5fffe0562776a2830c7b525ba9f641110d7a.pdf).

Unfortunately, those are not directly available to Ruby it seems so you may have to implement or link to the padding schemes. That said, as OAEP is not available either, that's hardly disqualifying them. Generally I'd just opt for ECDSA though and combine the message with the smaller signature format.

---

Note that private key operations are rather different than RSA public key operations. They generally rely on CRT parameters to be present. Furthermore, and probably more importantly, they need to have been designed *to protect the private key* against attacks such as side channel attacks. Just using a private key instead of a public key is not a good idea.

For a discussion of using OAEP for signature generation see the discussion [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29354/why-not-use-oaep-for-signatures). For info about if RSA encryption with a private key equals signature generation, see my own self-answered Q/A [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15997/1172).

Comment: Are you saying that encryption with the private key isn't actually encryption, it's signing, and that's why `PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING` isn't available? How can you recover the plaintext through public key decryption if it's a signature? And why is it bad?

Comment: Yes, I'm saying exactly that. And not just here, but also [on the crypto site](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/15998/1172). The recovery of plaintext is not possible *unless* a scheme with message recovery is used. Message recovery is not bad in itself; using the wrong padding mechanism for signature generation *is* however bad. OAEP was not designed for signature generation. A lot of the security of RSA is derived from the padding; RSA without padding is not even remotely secure (if messages can have any value).

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. I did not know that. Is RSA private key encryption using `PKCS1_PADDING` insecure as well, or is that OK?

Comment: There is no such as PKCS#1 padding. [PKCS#1 is a standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3447) that defines methods of using RSA. It is the first standard of RSA laboratories, started by Rivest, Shamir and Adleman - the RSA in RSA. It defines multiple padding methods including RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 (for encryption) and RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 (for signature schemes with appendix). Now that "appendix" is the message itself, indicating that you require the full message to perform signature verification. Using RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 padding for signature generation is not a good idea either.

Comment: Actually, PSS and OAEP are also defined in PKCS#1 as you may have seen. If you specify PKCS#1 for encryption then you'd expect RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 to be used, but some libraries will actually partly use RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 to support some weird SSL signature scheme that uses both MD5 and SHA1 concatenated together.

Comment: You're right, Ruby seems to use `RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5` for [private key encryption](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/RSA_private_encrypt.html), and that's what I have been (incorrectly) referring to as `PKCS1`. Thanks for those links and the clarification. Could I ask why private key encryption with `RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5` padding is insecure? Does it somehow compromise the private key/leak information?

Comment: I'm not sure. It certainly hasn't been proven to be secure, and there must be a reason why PSS exists, right? Both actually rely on the same construction called MGF(1). But besides that *I would not trust the implementation to be secure*, even if it would allow the private key. Note that the public key that is normally used for encryption *does not need to be protected against leakage*. Besides that, RSA modular exponentiation is often performed using RSA CRT parameters, something not even present in RSA public keys.